# How to map through different jsons and get data from an array

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have created 2 different jsons and I need to get the courseName from both jsons using one function and populate them in a dropdown

I am currently able to do this using a map function on both jsons in separate option tags within an input element

```
import React from 'react'
import MesaLinda from './MesaLinda.json';
import TijerasCreek from './TijerasCreek.json';
import { Form, FormGroup, Label, Input, Button } from 'reactstrap'
import '../App.css';


const course = (props) => {
    return (
        <Form>
            <FormGroup>
                <Label for="courseSelect">Course</Label>
                <Input type="select" name="select" id="courseSelect" >
                    {MesaLinda.CostaMesaCCMesaLinda.map((mesaLinda, index) => {
                        return <option>
                            {mesaLinda.courseName}
                        </option>
                    })}
                    {TijerasCreek.TijerasCreek.map((tijerasCreek, index) => {
                        return <option>
                            {tijerasCreek.courseName}
                        </option>
                    })}
                </Input>
            </FormGroup>
            <FormGroup>
```

I want to be able to use one map function to iterate through multiple different json files to get the courseName

Answer (score 0, accepted):

kasperlauge's answer is definitely great. If you're indeed planning on adding more and more jsons I'd suggest perhaps adding a function like this one outside of your current, and then calling it with an array of the jsons:

```
const jsonOptions = ( json ) => {
  return json.map( ( { courseName } ) => {
    return <options>
      { courseName }
    </options>;
  } );
};

const course = ( props ) => {
...
  <Input type="select" name="select" id="courseSelect">
    jsonOptions( [ 
      ...MesaLinda.CostaMesaCCMesaLinda, 
      ...TijerasCreek.TijerasCreek 
    ] )
  </Input>
...
```

It's just an alternative, I think it would scale better.
( Also note the destructuring inside the map(), it's very useful. )

Comment: Thanks both of you. I really learned a lot in a short amount of time. I haven’t tried the latest code from YannickK but I will when I get home. I’m sure we will cross paths again, since I will have many questions to ask.

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like:

```
import React from 'react'
import MesaLinda from './MesaLinda.json';
import TijerasCreek from './TijerasCreek.json';
import { Form, FormGroup, Label, Input, Button } from 'reactstrap'
import '../App.css';


const course = (props) => {
    return (
        <Form>
            <FormGroup>
                <Label for="courseSelect">Course</Label>
                <Input type="select" name="select" id="courseSelect" >
                    {[
                       ...MesaLinda.CostaMesaCCMesaLinda, 
                       ...TijerasCreek.TijerasCreek
                        ].map((json, index) => {
                        return <option>
                            {json.courseName}
                        </option>
                    })}
                </Input>
            </FormGroup>
         <FormGroup>
```

Concatenating two arrays using the spread operator, and then calling the same map function on it.

Comment: First off, i can't believe how fast you did that. I am completely new to programming and it takes me forever to figure something out.

If I add another json file to my react app I would have to add it to the spread operator. Is there a way to do it more dynamically? Meaning if I add another course json, I would not have to add it to the spread operator.

Comment: Imports are somewhat static (or at least often treated that way) so I am not sure such a solution would be pretty. But you could maybe do something like const json = [...require('./TijerasCreek.json'), ...require('./MesaLinda.json')]
I am not entirely sure that it is allowed to use the spread operator directly on require() and besides that, I am not even sure that it is a better solution.